# AWS uploads only git files, but needed the entire folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using elastic beanstalk, and after `eb deploy` it uploads only git files, but I need to upload the entire folder.

My config:

```
branch-defaults:
  develop:
    environment: App-dev
environment-defaults:
  App-dev:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: app-full
  default_ec2_keyname: app-eb
  default_platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Node.js running on
    64bit Amazon Linux/4.4.6
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

I choose to not using CodeCommit while set it up. But I suppose it uses `.gitignore` file while deciding what to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I added `.ebignore` file it started to archive an entire folder.